# My request is empty? PhP laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms, request

My request object is empty and I dont know why.

This is my form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route("report", $property)}}">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-check my-2">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="reason" id="not-for-sale" value="not-for-sale">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="radio-appartement">Deze woning is niet meer te koop</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check my-2">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="reason" id="wrong-info" value="wrong-info">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="radio-huis">De informatie bij deze woning klopt niet</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check my-2">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="reason" id="no-perm-residence" value="no-perm-residence">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="radio-rijtjeshuis">Deze woning mag niet permanent bewoond worden</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check my-2">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="reason" id="wrong-realtor" value="wrong-realtor">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="radio-rijtjeshuis">De makelaar die bij de woning is vermeld, klopt niet</label>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mt-5">
        <textarea class="form-control property-message-field" name="message" title="message" placeholder="Plaats hier verdere uitleg"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-message float-right" type="submit">Verzenden</button>
</form>
```

and this is my method where it is send 2:

```
public function report(Property $property, Request $request) {
    $target_email = config("mail.from.address");
    dd($request);
}
```

The dump and die method only shows:

> Request {#964}

I have no idea why my request stays empty.  The `$property` on the other hand works fine so I don't think the problem is with that.

Comment: This is my route btw:     
    Route::post( 'huren/{approved_property}/report', 'PropertyController@report' )
        ->name( 'report' );

Comment: if it's a POST request then csrf should be an inout box. You have to send it back to server.

Comment: {{csrf_field()}} will generate the CSRF input in the DOM

Comment: try `dd($request->all())`;

Comment: amku91 and Dammeul I dont really know what you guys mean. other forms with method: POST in my application also have the csrf field in the same exact way. @Aakash Tushar I tried but it gives me an 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::all()' error

Comment: You should be using `Illuminate\Http\Request`. check again you must have used wrong class in namespace

Comment: in your controller file use Illuminate\Http\Request; do you have this ? @RikvanToorn

Comment: @AakashTushar That was it. I had something similar but now it's fixed. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make `Request` the first parameter. Try this:

```
//make Request the first parameter
public function report(Request $request, Property $property) {
    $target_email = config("mail.from.address");
    dd($request);
}
```